# rails caching with anonymous classes

Tags: ruby, caching, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I want to cache the results of several large queries in an fragment cache.

I could store the values in a hash and then retrieve them before making the request, but I'm wondering if the processing request could be deferred until the data is actually needed.

Here is the before code:

```
# controller

class MyController < ApplicationController
  def my_action
    @my_huge_query_with_1_result = do_massive_question
  end
end

# my_action.html.slim

.header
  = cache do
    ' Your answer is
    = @my_huge_query_with_1_result
```

This is what I would LIKE the code to look like, with an anonymous object.  However, I can't figure out how to pass in parameters.

```
# controller

class MyController < ApplicationController
  def my_action
    @my_cache = Object.new
    def @my_cache.do_query
      do_massive_question(params) # this fails; because params is not in the scope of @my_cache's class.
    end
  end
end

# my_action.html.slim

.header
  = cache do
    ' Your answer is
    = @my_cache.do_query
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to defer the processing until the very end?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way to do this is with Procs/lambdas. You would then invoke it with `#call`.

```
def my_action
  @my_huge_query_with_1_result = ->{ do_massive_question(params) }
end

# View
.header
  = cache do
    ' Your answer is
    = @my_huge_query_with_1_result.call
```

Comment: facepalm! I can't believe I over looked that.  Probably too much time with classes and modules.  :)